# Creating a web method in Java JAX WS implementation that accepts xml as parameter

Tags: java, xml, jax-ws

Want to create a web method in java jax ws that can accept a xml through SOAP Request xml. I am using below code but getting error.

```
@WebMethod(operationName="CreateNewRequest")
@WebResult(name="CREATE_REQ_RESP") 
@XmlElement(name="CREATE_REQ_RESP") 
public String getCreateNewRequestXml(
      @WebParam(name="CREATE_WI_REQ") 
      @XmlElement(name="CREATE_WI_REQ") Source createReqXml) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: can u show the exception?

Comment: Exception is null pointer and its coming because value of param createReqXml is being received as null.

Comment: Sample request: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="A">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <a:CreateWINew>
         <CREATE_WI_REQ>
//xml to be sent to web method comes here 
 </CREATE_WI_REQ>
      </a:CreateWINew>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>